# PL/pgSQL: Update a table using a record

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, upsert, database-trigger

I have an insert trigger in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database which copies the row being inserted to another table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_record_insert () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $x$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO data_record_backup VALUES ($1.*)' USING new;
  RETURN new;
END;
$x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

However, I want to be able to use Postgres' `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` upsert statement to insert rows into these tables but can't figure out how to write the trigger.  It'd be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_record_insert () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $x$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO data_record_backup VALUES ($1.*)
           ON CONFLICT (pk) DO UPDATE SET column_names($1) = $1.*' USING new;
  RETURN new;
END;
$x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

But obviously that `SET column_names($1) = $1.*` is wrong, it's just something I made up.  Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that `new` may contain an arbitrary subset of the columns of `data_record_backup`.

Comment: There is no direct way. You must explicitly state all column names (and values) after `UPDATE SET`. However, you could build up that SQL dynamically (you already use `EXECUTE` + populating an `hstore` or `json[b]` value from the record & querying their keys should give you the attribute names -- for tables there is the `information_schema` to query too). Note, that if `NEW` is only a subset, you need to explicitly state the column names in the `INSERT` part too.

Comment: That explains another bug on my list of things to look into...  Thanks.

Comment: I came across this which might also be relevant, but haven't tried it yet: http://pgxn.org/dist/colnames/

Comment: On second thought, because this will be in a trigger, `NEW`'s type is always a table (relation). You could just use the [`TG_TABLE_NAME` & `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` trigger variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) to query its columns (no need dirty hacks for that).

Comment: Um, really?  So will `NEW` always have all columns of the table, even if the `INSERT` that triggered it only has some of them specified?

Comment: Exactly. `NEW` & `OLD` always fully populated. When you wrote *subset of the columns* I thought that it means that you'll use this trigger on multiple tables, and some of them only have the subset of columns (of `data_record_backup`). -- Partial `UPDATE` & `INSERT`'s triggers' `NEW` & `OLD` contains all columns, even the ones which are not mentioned in those statements (in case of `INSERT`, they will be the already calculated defaults).

Comment: Please see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747803/pl-pgsql-updating-a-table-from-a-record